# Error while opening an HTTPS link through WebView

Tags: facebook, react-native

I try to open a WebView on https://facebook.com in my React Native app and get the following error:

Encountered an error on loading page: {"target": 419, "description": "An SSL error has occured and a secured connection to the server cannot be made"...}

I'm testing on an iPhone Xr emulator.
What could I be doing wrong?

Here is the line

```
<WebView injectedJavaScript={jscode} source={{ uri: viewUri }} />
```

Comment: Sure that the HTTPS link is not self-signed? I couldn't connect, not even with NSAllowsArbitraryLoads activated, to a HTTPS self-signed certificate

Answer (score 0):

Add following lines in **Info.plist**

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
  <dict>
      <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
      <true/>
  </dict>
```